# Cost of constantly querying an associated nested model (does activerecord cache results?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

Let's say I have `User` model with a `boolean` flag called `email_notifications`. This lets us know whether this user cares to receive email notifications from the app.

Recently I've been moving all these flags and settings into a separate sub-model call `Preference` to keep it away from the core user model. A `User` `has_one` `Preference`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :preference, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :preference

  scope :email_recipients, -> { where(preference: { email_notification: true} ) }

  def can_receive_email?
    preference.email_notification
  end
end
```

As you can see, I have a helper scope and a helper method on the model.

However, now that it lives in another table, I have always query the association `:preference` first and then get the value I need. It's not directly available from the `User` model itself any more.

Is this considered bad practice? Or does Rails help out and cache associated models so it doesn't have to re-query every time? I like organizing my various configs in a separate model, which I DO think is good practice, but this potential cost of constantly re-querying is stopping me.

Thanks!

*EDIT:*

I'm aware that I can do `User.includes(:preference).blah_blah`, however I want to avoid updating this in EVERY place where I call the user, and it may not always be known ahead of time whether I'm going to query the sub-model and need to include an `.includes()`

Answer (score 1):

Rails associations are stored in memory after they're accessed so calling `user.preference` wouldn't hit the database except for the first time it's referenced.

Also, `includes` wouldn't have much of an effect in this case since this is a `has_one`. `includes` is usually useful for eager loading many associations in a single larger query rather than hitting the database each time a child object is called.